# XIB actualization problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, xib

I'm facing a weird problem dealing with Xcode. When I run my project using simulator I got the correct xib showing, but when I select my iPhone as target, it shows an older version of that xib... I'm going crazy with this, I have tried to clean targets, deleting and reinstalling the app on iphone, :^S
Please could anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Comment: Just a thought: Does the older xib still exist in the project folder? Have you completely shut down Xcode/IB, then relaunched, and checked that both the Xcode project and IB are pointing to the correct xib? I've found that IB holds on to old connections like a terrier.

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks very much for your help. I have fix the problem by deleting the xib and his viewcontroller files and restoring from a backup. As you suggested the problem seems to be related to the files in source directories :^) but i´m still speechless about the fact simulator shows the last version of the xib and not the device... O_o

Comment: Yep, the simulator/iPhone mismatch is weird. There must be a lot of seriously complicated gearwork going on to keep Xcode/IB/simulator/debugger/device/files coordinated. Glad you escaped from between the cogs.

Comment: I just remembered a tip from early tutorials that makes this problem seem even weirder. When you run successive versions in the simulator, you are advised to do iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings on occasion, because the simulator holds onto old versions. But what you were experiencing was the reverse. Anyway, all's well that ends well.

Comment: Wienke, that solved it for me. Wierd that it caches stuff that has obviously changed.

Answer (score 0):

When Xcode installs development builds of iOS apps on the simulator and on the device, it copies all files from the `.app` bundle into the target directory for the app in the simulator or on the device. However, it does **not** remove old files. This can sometimes cause strange effects.

For example:

You have `MyView~ipad.xib` and `MyView.xib` for iPhone, you install the app and run it on the device, now you decide to delete the `MyView~ipad.xib` so that it will just use the `MyView.xib` same as iPhone, you test this in the simulator and it works fine but when you put it on the device again it still uses the old iPad xib file, but how when it's not even in the project any more? Well the old file still exists in the filesystem on the device until you actually delete the app off the device.

This can happen when you remove files from the project or rename them to something else, the old files will still be there and especially if you have fall-back beaviour or how iOS can look for other suffixes automatically like @2x or ~ipad - this can easily cause confusion. Check for this whenever you notice strange effects like old versions of files seem to resurrect themselves, or it works on one device but not the other.